Is there a way to take a cross-database advisory lock in PostgreSQL?
This is a follow up to Advisory locks: private to connected database or shared across cluster? where it turns out that the space of advisory locks in PostgreSQL are private to a single database.
So is there a way to take an exclusive advisory lock that is cross database?
(My use case is where I’m creating/deleting grants/roles/memberships a lot, and using advisory locks to avoid “tuple concurrently updated” and “tuple concurrently deleted errors”. On a single database this works fine I think, but I am wondering on options for a multi database environment, because roles are global/shared, and pg_database, where connect grants are stored, is also global/shared)

I don't think there is a way. Catch and handle the errors.
